# React router: reload new page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

For example I have this routes:

- /login: for login screen
- /home: for home screen

At Home screen, I logout, and I want it come to again /login screen as loading new page (so all states are new). How can I do that in React using React router.

Comment: `window.location = '/login'` ? Can you provide more context? React doesn't provide routing. How do you currently do the routing?

Comment: I have edited my question. I'm using React Router library. thanks for your comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically navigate using react router](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router)

Answer (score 0):

You can 'redirect' like this:

```
import { browserHistory } from "react-router";

browserHistory.push('/someroute');
```

And if you want to reset your state - do it in `componentWillReceiveProps`

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  var currentLocation = nextProps.location.pathname;
  if(currentLocation=='someroute')
    //your logic
  }
```